# float element doesn't affect height

Tags: html, css

I know there are already many posts on this topic, but I just can't manage to get this to work, so sorry for that..

So i have 2 div elements next to eachother, the left one is a normal static one and the right one is a float, but it doesn't affect the height of it's parent. How can I fix this annoying problem?

```
<div id="content">
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
<div id="articles">
</div>
</div>

#content {
    background-color: #efefef;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    margin: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

#articles {
    width: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 25px;
    font-family: reef;
}

#sidebar {
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: you haven't set any rule for the height as I can see from your code

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle for it?

Answer (score 1):

Clearfix the container

```
#content:before,
#content:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

#clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

The above snippet is from html5boilerplate. The authors state for the above solution:

> 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
>       `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document. Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of
>      elements that receive the `clearfix` class.
> 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.

Answer (score 0):

try setting `overflow:hidden` for #content.

This post has some more info on why this can solve the float-container-height problem:
[Overflow:hidden in float. Does it hide anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255813/overflowhidden-in-float-does-it-hide-anything)

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of why this answers the question

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the css to position relative...

```
#sidebar {
margin-right: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
float: right;
position: relative;
```

}

http://codepen.io/bevanz/pen/VLrbxJ <- might be an issue with not having content in the div aswell. Mycode pen shows what i mean!